# visual studio code ssh multiple connections for php

Tags: php, ssh, visual-studio-code, sftp

i would like to give a try to Microsoft Visual Studio Code, one of the main things that i need is the possibility to manage multiple connections through SSH at the same time to edit my php, Smarty and javascript files.

Is there the possibility or a plugin like "Remote System Explorer" for Eclipse that permit the use of this function?
Otherwise i'll go on with Eclipse

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you look into the documentation of VS Code?

Comment: obviously yes, i already tried the existent ssh plugins, and they are ok if you manage only one project a time.

Comment: Is it possible to use VSCode to do remote SSH where the destination IP & PORT are dynamic. I have a requirement to connect to remote serverB via serverA. When I login to serverA, I am redirected to serverB based on sshd_configs on serverA. when I do ssh via cmd line it goes fine to serverB. But VSCode is not able to do that. Any ideas?