# Visual Studio Code - Multiple Remote SSH connections in one workspace?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access

I have recently come to love Visual Studio Code and the Remote SSH extension. It's really revolutionized my workflow.  However I find myself keeping multiple windows open with different connections to different servers. I just discovered that you can add a different folder to the same workspace, however when connected to a remote server I only have the option to add another folder on that server or a local one.

Is there any way to add a DIFFERENT remote connection to an existing workspace?

(I'm aware [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828394/visual-studio-code-ssh-multiple-connections-for-php) already MAYBE touched on this, but it's a little unclear exactly what he's asking, so I figured I would inquire more clearly.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After much research and trial and error it seems this is not possible. What you CAN do is add multiple folders from the same remote computer. So I've redone my workflow to use that functionality instead.

Comment: Is it possible to use VSCode to do remote SSH where the destination IP & PORT are dynamic. I have a requirement to connect to remote serverB via serverA. When I login to serverA, I am redirected to serverB based on sshd_configs on serverA. when I do ssh via cmd line it goes fine to serverB. But VSCode is not able to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you use multiple folders from the same remote computer?

Comment: @Nathan It's pretty easy, make sure you've got your remote workspace open, then click File -> Add Folder to Workspace. It will pop up a folder picker showing your remote filesystem.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. And thanks for responding to an answer from 3 years ago :P