# VS Code: Connecting to a python interpreter in docker container without using remote containers

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I know it is generally possible to connect to a container's python interpreter with:

- remote containers
- remote ssh

The problems I have with these solutions:

- it opens a new window where I need to install/specify all extensions again
- it opens a new window per container. I am working in a monorepo where each services's folder is mounted in a different container (connected via docker compose)

Is there a solution that allows me to specify a remote container to connect to simply for the python interpreter (and not for an entirely new workspace)?

Comment: Have you tried to use `"remote.SSH.defaultExtensions"` ?

Comment: I would prefer if whoever was opening the workspace could use whatever extensions/configuration they have on their local installation. Remote ssh doesn't solve the one window per container problem either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58350537/6309), it is still not possible to open multiple remote (SSH/Container) inside the same VSCode workspace/window.

If possible, try and adapt your workflow to:

- have multiple python container running on the same remote server, each one mounting a different remote server folder, one per project
- have *one* remote SSH connection to that remote server (which, again, is already running the python containers, one per project)
- open *multiple* (remote) folder within your current workspace.

That way, you are decoupling:

- the development environment (multiple projects, with their respective python containers)
- from the development IDE (one local VSCode instance, connected through one SSH session to the development server).

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Like Remote Containers, one issue with VS Code's Remote SSH plugin is it requires you to re-setup your vscode environment (plugins/config) again. I'd prefer to avoid this as the different people working on this repository have different configurations.

Comment: @rbhalla True, and not all plugins are available through a remote SSH session anyway. Could you use a remote Container session, connecting to one remote container, which would have bind-mounted *all* the necessary (remote) host folders?

Comment: It is possible to have a docker-in-docker setup, but again, it requires VS Code to be setup again with plugins/config.